# For a property declared outside of constructor, is it overkill to initialize its value to null inside the constructor?

Tags: php

I was looking at this implementation of a single linked list and noticed that inside the constructor the property `$this->next` is set to `null`.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576498-implementation-of-a-single-linked-list-in-php/

Since php automatically sets the value of the property `$next` to `null` when it is declared outside of the constructor (ex `public $next`), isn't the line of code `$this->next = NULL` overkill?

```
class ListNode
{
    public $data;
    public $next;

    function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->next = NULL;
    }

    function readNode()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Also - I've seen this convention be used several times in php OOP.  Is this a required convention in some other language?

Comment: It's good practice to declare the variables.

Comment: I know - but in the case removing the line of code `$this->next = NULL` isn't the runtime behavior the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->next already is NULL, so there is no need to redeclare it.